# Given $a \neq b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ determine $c$, in the line $ab$, s.t. $c \perp b-a$. Conclude that $\forall x \in ab$, with $x \neq c$, $|c|<|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The line joining points $a$ and $b$ is defined by the following set:

$$ ab = \{ (1-t) \cdot a + t \cdot b; t \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

Note $t \in [0,1]$

$$ c \in ab \implies \exists t_1 \in [0,1] \text{ s.t. } (1-t_1) \cdot a + t_1 \cdot b = c $$

Manipulating the expression, we have:

$$ (1-t_1) \cdot a + t_1 \cdot b = c $$

$$ \implies a - a \cdot t_1 + t_1 \cdot b = c $$

$$ \therefore a - t_1 \cdot (b-a) = c $$

Similarly, for $x$, we have:
$$x \in ab \implies \exists t_2 \in [0,1] \text{ s.t. } (1-t_2) \cdot a + t_2 \cdot b = x $$

$$ \therefore a - t_2 \cdot (b-a) = x $$

We know:

$$c \perp b-a \implies \langle(b-a), c \rangle = 0$$

How can I use this last piece of information to continue the exercise? Am I on the right track? If so, how can I finalise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake, it should be $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}+t_{1}\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)$ and $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}+t_{2}\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)$. The trick is to notice that any point $\mathbf{x}$ on line $\mathbf{ab}$ is equal to a scaled $\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}$ added to  $\mathbf{c}$:

$$
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{c}+\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)
$$

Then, we can simply substitute to the expression we want to check.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\mathbf{x}\right|^{2}
&=
\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}
\\
&=
\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{c}
+
2\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)\left[\mathbf{c}\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)\right]
+
\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)^{2}\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)
\\
&=
\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{c}
+
\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)^{2}\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)
\\
&>
\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{c}
\\
&=
\left|\mathbf{c}\right|^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

From the second to third line, we use the orthogonality $\mathbf{c}\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)$. From the third to fourth line, we use $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{c}\implies t_{1}\neq t_{2}$. And that's how to show that $\left|\mathbf{x}\right|>\left|\mathbf{c}\right|$

**Remarks**

If you operate in a different inner product space, you can replace the dot product with the inner product $\left\langle\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle$ instead and the answer will still be valid.

This is a common method: split a vector into orthogonal components

$$
\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i}c_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i},
\phantom{x}
\left\langle\mathbf{v}_{p},\mathbf{v}_{q}\right\rangle
=
0
\phantom{x}
\forall
\phantom{x}
p\neq q
$$

Then the squared norm (induced by the inner product) is

$$
\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|^{2}
=
\sum_{i}c_{i}^{2}\left\|\mathbf{v}_{i}\right\|^{2}
$$